# What if I don't heed the warning "hides inherited member. To make the current member override that implementation...."

Tags: c#, warnings, virtual-functions

This is maybe a fine point, but it concerns the warning that the compiler issues if you do something like:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void F() { }
}
class B : A
{
    public void F() { }
}
```

Then you get the warning:

`'EomApp1.B.F()' hides inherited member 'EomApp1.A.F()'.

To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise use the new keyword.`

[image: image of error message]

QUESTION: What is the warning actually warning me will happen if I do nothing about it? Will my program function differently if I add the 'new' keyword vs. if I do not?

(Note: I know I could test this easily enough but I figured it was worth asking here)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It will not do anything but the method you have there F() is also not polymorphic. It becomes very easy to make mistake in code if you started to use base class reference hence you are warned. Of course it can be what you want, hence the new keyword just make it more explicit

E.g.

```
B b1 = new B();
b1.F(); // will call B.F()

A b2 = new B();
b2.F(); // will call A.F()
```

Now, if you add class `C` with `new`, it will behave the same as `B`. If you add class `D` with `override`, then `F` becomes polymorphic:

```
class C : A
{
    public new void F() { }
}

class D : A
{
    public override void F() { }
}

// Later

C c1 = new C();
c1.F(); // will call C.F()

A c2 = new C();
c2.F(); // will call A.F()

D d1 = new D();
d1.F(); // will call D.F()

A d2 = new D();
d2.F(); // will call D.F()
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8bKti2).

Comment: Try it on VS, but I believe it will call A.F()

Answer (score 28):

No, the default behaviour is exactly the same as if you use `new`, other than whether the warning is given. In my experience you more often *actually* want to specify `override` instead of `new`, as it's usually just a case of forgetting to explicitly override.

If you really *do* want a completely separate method, and if you've got the *option* of using a different name instead, I'd take that approach. Having one method hiding another *usually* reduces readability significantly IMO. It's not *too* bad if the purpose is to just give a more specific return type (and you make sure the more weakly typed method returns the same value), but that's a pretty rare case.

Answer (score 0):

This is just warning. Code will work. In some circumstance, this warning can lead to some problem.

use **new** keyword with the method which you are calling from the base class.

```
class A
{
    public virtual void F() { }
}
class B : A
{
   new public void F() { }
}
```

### Reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135(v=vs.71).aspx